# When is Datagridview's Paint and Cellpainting called?

Tags: c#, datagridview, draw, paint, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a Datagridview `dgv`, let's say with 3 of the columns I want to affect manually are :

```
col1 : DataGridviewTextboxColumn, for displaying a number

col2 : DataGridviewTextboxColumn, used as a color indicator, without text. BackColor will will be changed later.

col3 : DataGridviewImageColumn
```

Other columns are binded with their respective `DataPropertyName` of the underlying `Datasource`. The 3 columns above are not binded to any `DataPropertyName` and to be affected manually, for example when I want to change the image or color indicator.

Every time I affect the `DataSource`, I do a datasource rebind and `dgv.Invalidate()` to update the grid's graphic.

1. When and how do I ask the `dgv` to take into account the manual values in 3 edited columns ? Previously I manually affect the 3 above column inside `dgv_CellPainting`. It will work but CellPainting takes a long time and we decide to remove it. I tried putting them inside `dgv_Paint` (which I used for merging headers) but it does not take the color nor the image.

With CellPainting : rectangles for spaces between rows, filling the background, separater between rows, boxes for image and color, etc. The 3 columns I am refering to are the first column (index), color and image (in boxes) columns. Other image are constant.

[image]

Without CellPainting: No row and column separation. I created a pseudo row separation by setting grid's cell border to horizontal.

[image]

2. When is `CellPainting` and `Paint` called? What is the execution order and their difference? My rough understanding is that they are called when the cell/grid "need to be repainted". But I notice they are called multiple times, not just when I call `Invalidate()` but even when I hover the mouse over the grid region.

Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, you got that right, it is called quie often. If you have a perfomance problem you may want to try limiting the actions to certain rows&columns. what/how much are you doing in the cellpainting event? maybe it can be optimized? eg: calling the built-in methods as much as possible will yield in a better performance instead of using drawstring etc all the time..

Comment: Yes I did try to limit to the max the cellpainting, only create rectangles (so that rows do not touch each other), fill those with colored pen (following MDSN's https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ), the rest I call e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);to avoid DrawString, DrawImage, etc.
Even then it is slow.

Comment: @TaW: What do you mean by "if that is all"? Then if I want to affect the manually-edited columns, when should it be done?

Comment: Sorry I caught an early version of your comment, containing only e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);`` - Now things look different..! Hm, how many rows and cols are there?

Comment: 9 columns: 4 image columns and 5 text columns. The lagginess begins to show at 4-5th rows. Basically when I resize the winform TaskPane horizontally (it's a winform taskpane application for Excel) the grid takes time to be fully painted.

Comment: The numbers sond like nothing. otoh: imagecolumns could be more than that. do you (have to) draw these in the cellpainting event?

Comment: No I don't. I use Cellpainting just for painting the layout (rectangles for spaces between rows, filling the background, separater between rows, etc.). The rest I let PaintContent handle. There is no manual content painting inside Cellpainting. For brushes, I follow [using Brush = new Brush(...)] for not repeating the brush, as recommended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80198/discussion-between-taw-and-kenny).